# Image and destination URL

Tags: image, url, facebook-like

I am trying to set a like button on page A for another page : B.
I explain. I have on my site a gallery of image made by a flash program.
When liking th eimage on the A page, i want facebook to display the image and a link to the page b (which will display the flash program preconfigured with the image).

i have tried to set the "og" meta with "B page url", the corerct image ... but it does not work.

COuld anyone help me on that ?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the like button to below the image or whatever do this

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR_URL_TO_BE_LIKED" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```